# Unable to auto close Vue-strap after specified duration

Tags: vue.js, vue-strap

I am using Vue-strap alert component with Vue.js. The alert box works fine, however, I am unable to auto close the alert box after specified duration. Here is the component code I am using.

```
 <alert :show.sync="showAlert" placement="top" duration="3000" type="success" width="400px" dismissable>
      <span class="icon-info-circled alert-icon-float-left"></span>
      <strong>Success</strong>
      <p>{{alertMessage}}</p> 
    </alert>
```

The alert box remains open and close on clicking the close (x) button. Here is a code pen that uses the alert component.

 
https://codepen.io/Taxali/pen/dKJpKY

Any suggestion, how to auto close the alert box after 3 seconds? Thanks.

Comment: As stated [in the github](https://github.com/yuche/vue-strap) for this project, "SORRY, THIS PROJECT IS NO LONGER MAINTAINED".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [source code](https://github.com/yuche/vue-strap/blob/9c7c0bf1c1ea8c704e62bfc8111c8fd794921c53/src/Alert.vue#L56), setTimeout(_, duration) is only set if `show` props is change. 
So there is a workaround, you can toggle `show` from `false` to `true` in `mounted` methods, or you can use a button to toggle the alert.

Another way to `setTimeout` yourself in Vue component.

```js
 var vm = new Vue({
    components: {
        alert:VueStrap.alert,
    },
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        alertMessage:"Activity Saved Successfully.",
        showAlert:false
    },
    mounted() {
      this.showAlert = true
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-strap/1.1.40/vue-strap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="app">
  
  <alert :show.sync="showAlert" placement="top" :duration="3000" type="success" width="400px" dismissable >
   <span class="icon-info-circled alert-icon-float-left"></span>
   <strong>Success</strong>
   <p>{{alertMessage}}</p> 
 </alert>
  
</div>
```